# Can't download python--setuptools for Homebrew in China

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, blocked

guys, I've spent hours struggling to install python via **Homebrew** on my Mac.

I've tried `brew install python` and `brew fetch python` for a few times but both failed to download `python--setuptools`. I believed that it may be due to the GFW in China. I have been using VPN so I downloaded the `setuptools-19.4.tar.gz` (~ 642 KB) to the `brew --cache` (`/Library/Caches/Homebrew` in my case) but it seems that Homebrew only recognises `python-2.7.11.tgz` but not `setuptools-19.4.tar.gz` as you can see from the screenshot below.

[image]

Any idea to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want do actually? Install python interpreter or any other package?

Comment: maybe you need a better VPN

Comment: did you try connecting to the url on a browser to see if the site is even available to you? Otherwise to echo another sentiment; maybe you need a better VPN.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Yep... I use the VPN built on my own VPS and it works...

Comment: @Greg Thx. I changed VPN and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you likely need a better VPN to burn through TGF.